# How to set GNOME Terminal to scroll a fixed number of lines with the mouse wheel?

Tags: gnome-terminal

GNOME Terminal 3.4.1.1 in Ubuntu 12.04 has an IMO weird mouse scroll behavior: A single mouse wheel motion scrolls `ceiling($LINES / 10)` lines, rather than a set number. That is, if the terminal window is between 31 and 40 lines, it will scroll four lines at a time. If it's 100 lines, it will scroll 10 lines at a time. How can I force it to work like other applications, **scrolling N lines regardless of the window height?**

Comment: I'm planning to fix it: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=748012 Could you please comment _there_ if you have a firm opinion on how many lines it should be?